# remove any occurence of a "(...)" from a long string, where "..." could be anything

Tags: python, regex

I am currently using the following code to try and remove the characters from the string but nothing is being removed. I think it has to do with the fact that the sequence of characters I am trying to remove are between parantheses. So for example, in the following string, "-McQuay International, 13600 Industrial Park Blvd, (p) ", I would want to remove "(p)"

```
import re

regexp = " \(*\) "
text = re.sub(regexp, "", "-McQuay International, 13600 Industrial Park Blvd, (p)")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the following regex replacement:

```py
inp = "-McQuay International, 13600 Industrial Park Blvd, (p)"
output = re.sub(r'\s*\(.*?\)\s*', ' ', inp).strip()
print(output)  # -McQuay International, 13600 Industrial Park Blvd,
```

First, you should be using lazy dog when matching parentheses.  This is to avoid matching across multiple sets of parentheses, should your text have that.  Second, I use a replacement which also removes unwanted whitespace.  The call to `strip()` will remove any leading/trailing whitespace which might be left over.

Answer (score 0):

`regexp = "\(|\)"`

Try this